# No Module named 'requests'

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code showing error,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Even though module is installed.

I tried deleting and installing the module again too.
But it still doesn't run.

Comment: Can you add some more information like your folder structure and etc. also can you check if you're installing in the correct environment?

Comment: do you use the correct python intepreter in vs code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed the **requests** package correctly, you can check with the following command. This will also get the location where **requests** is installed.

```
pip show requests
```

[image]

Then choose the correct interpreter for vscode.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python:Select Interpreter**

  [image]
- Select the interpreter with **requests** installed

  [image]